# How to access the collider in an OnTriggerEnter function outside of the function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created two functions. An OnTriggerEnter function that can detect when I am colliding with a door and one for when I click "E". I have also created a function that detects when both have happened at the same time, which I was going to use to actually open the door. However for now I do not have a way to access the "collider" from the OnTriggerEnter function.

EDIT:
I have gotten rid of the eClick variable and created the collider1 variable which refers to the doors boxcollider. I was recommended an approach by @derHugo which helped clean up my code however my console log would say "door would open" whenever I clicked E even when I was not colliding with the door I edited the code some more but I got the same results. Any ideas?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InteractionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool doorCollision; 
    [SerializeField] Collider collider1;

     void Start() 
    {
        collider1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("door").GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && doorCollision)
        {
            Debug.Log("door would open");
        }  
    }
    
  
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) //"collider" is the door
    {
        if (collider1 = collider)
        {
          doorCollision = true;
        }
        else
        {
            doorCollision = false;
        }
    }
    

}
```

I have tried creating a public collider object and then getting the parent of the object, (which would be the door) but I have not figured out a way to do that. All the help I get will be forever appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: It sort of looks like you wanted to stash the door game object into a private variable where you wrote `collider = collider1`.  You actually stored the `collider1` property into the function parameter `collider` - likely a mistake.  Probably want a private field in your class called `doorToOpen` or something and set `doorToOpen = collider.gameObject;` and then where you have `I wanna rotate the door here` You can do so with `doorToOpen`.

Answer (score 0):

You confused the order

```
 // This assigns collider1 -> collider
 // which is then never used further
 collider = collider1;
```

should rather be

```
 // This rather assigns collider -> collider1
 // so you can later on use collider1 within Update
 collider1 = collider;
```

then further the `doorCollision` and also `eClick` are completely redundant. Just make sure to reset the `collider1` instead

```
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider) 
{
    if(collider1 == collider) collider1 = null;
}
```

and then do

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && collider1)
    {
        // do something with collider1 here
    }
}
```

You might then consider renaming `collider1` to something like e.g. `currentDoor`.

---

So to take it to the next level I would rather have something like e.g.

```
// General interface for just any object you can interact with
public interface IInteractable
{
    void Interact();
}
```

Then have a dedicated script on your doors like e.g.

```
// Dedicated component for doors
public class Door : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    // Adjust these via the Inspector

    [Tooltip("Local Euler angles for the closed state")]
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 closedLocalEulerAngles;
    [Tooltip("Local Euler angles for the opened state")]
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 openedLocalEulerAngles = Vector3.up * 90;
    [Tooltip("How long it should take to rotate from fully closed to fully opened state")]
    [SerializeField][Min(0f)] private float rotateDuration = 0.5f; 
    [Tooltip("Which state shall the door start in?")]
    [SerilaizeField] private bool startOpened;

    // flag for h current opened state of the door
    private bool isOpen;

    private void Start()
    {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(startOpened ? openedLocalEulerAngles : closedLocalEulerAngles);
        isOpen = startOpened;
    }

    public void Interact()
    {
        // cancel eventually active routine
        StopAllCoroutines();
        
        // simply invert the current opened state
        isOpen = !isOpen;

        // start a new routine to apply rotation
        StartCoroutine(RotateRoutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator RotateRoutine()
    {
        // store the initial rotation
        var currentRotation = transform.localRotation;
        // the two possible target rotations
        var openRotation = Quaternion.Euler(openLocalEulerAngles);
        var closedRotation = Quaternion.Euler(closedLocalEulerAngles);
        // select the target rotation according to the current opened state
        var targetRotation = isOpen ? openRotation : closedRotation;

        // calculate the actual duration
        // In case you rapidly click the E-Key twice you do not want the last rotation to take the entire rotateDuration 
        // but rather apply it to the actual distance that needs to be rotated relative to the maximum distance
        var duration = rotateDuration * Quaternion.Angle(currentRotation, targetRotation) / Quaternion.Angle(openRotation, closedRotation);

        // iterates for "duration" seconds
        for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < duration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            // a factor moving from 0 to 1 within "duration" seconds
            var factor = timePassed / duration;
            // optional ease in and out
            factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

            // interpolate and apply the rotaion
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, factor);

            // "pause" the routine here, let Unity render this frame
            // and continue from here in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }

        // to be sure to terminate with clean values
        transform.localRotation = targetRotation;
    }
}
```

This way you can reuse your `InteractionScript` not only for doors but anything implementing the `IInteractable` doing e.g.

```
public class InteractionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // stores the currently overlapping interactable
    private IInteractable currentInteractable;
     
    private void Update()
    {
        // is E pressed and there currently is an interactable overlapping?
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && currentInteractable)
        {
            // then interact with it
            currentInteractable.Interact();
        }
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) 
    {
        // to avoid multiple interactables overwriting each other
        // we stick to the first one
        if(!currentInteractable)
        {
            // if there is an "IInteractable" on the collider it will be stored in currentInteractable
            collider.TryGetComponent(out currentInteractable));
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider) 
    {
        // only reset if the collider exiting is actually the one we are currently interacting with
        if (collider.TryGetComponent<IInteractable>(out var interactable) && interactable == currentInteractable)
        {
            currentInteractable = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is by far the most detailed response I have ever recieved. I have   edited my post after trying your approach

Comment: @PaulHabchy I think you still missed a bit the general idea: You don't need to use `Find` .. in the collision you already get the door anyway - also you might be able to interact with multiple and not only one single door in your scene ;) Instead of `doorCollision = true;` you rather want to store the `currentDoor = collider;` instead

Comment: @PaulHabchy your new issue with your edited code is that you now never reset the `doorCollision = false` when you **exit** the door trigger .. you only reset it in case you **enter** something else .. as said I would rather stick to what I provided at the bottom of my answer .. it is way more extendible and requires only one single component to interact with many different types of objects

Comment: I've done it! And all I needed was an OnTriggerExit function to go with the OnTriggerEnter function. Thank you truly got your help it will not be forgotten